# How to set custom Attributes to TextField in vaadin

Tags: vaadin

Am using Vaadin 7 and want to add a custom attribute - title for text field HTML rendered

something like

could i use designContext.setCustomAttribute(

if so, how do i get designContext after creating a textfield

Comment: Are you trying to attach some semantic value along with your widget, your `TextField`? Something like an identifier? Or are you talking about embedding extra HTML for rendering on the page? You Question is not clear. Perhaps you can edit to clarify, add a bit more description.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that from server-side Java code alone, you will need either some JavaScript or some GWT code. There's also a helpful add-on for that specific purpose you might want to check out: https://vaadin.com/directory/component/htmlattributehandler